Was idolatry the sin of the builders of the Tower of Babel?
Many commentators bemoan the fact that the sin of the builders of the Tower of Babel is not mentioned explicitly in the Torah.  A plurality (but by no means all) seems to believe they engaged in idolatry.  For example, the Talmud says:

Rabbi Natan says: All of them intended to build the tower for the sake of idol worship. They said: “And let us make a name for ourselves”, and God said [in Exodus 23:13]: “And make no mention of the name of other gods”. In both cases, the word “name” is used to talk about idol worship. [Sanhedrin 109a]

The Midrash says:

They said: “How arrogant of [God] to select the upper reaches for Himself and to give us the lower reaches. Instead, let us come and make a tower and craft an idol at its top, place a sword in its hand, and it will appear as though it is waging war against Him.” [Genesis Rabbah 38:6-9]

My question is this.  Idolatry is the big bugaboo in Tanakh and Talmud, and it is mentioned by name in spades when it occurs.  Why wouldn't it be mentioned by name here?

Good question. First instinct is Rambam's first halachos of Hilchot Avodah Zara
